# How to populate datagridview with dataset from select query?

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a search bar using SELECT query and I want to transfer the results to a DataGridView. But I always get an empty DataGridView.

Nothing is wrong with the query, I already tried to input it manually in access. What am I doing wrong in the code? Here it is:

```
Using conn = New OleDbConnection(connstring)
    Try
        Dim Sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE [Product Name] LIKE '" & txtSearchProduct.Text & "*'"

        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(Sql, conn)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds)
        DataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

    Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
    End Try
End Using
```

Comment: I think you are missing a line before setting Datasource to DataGridView : DataGridView2.AutoGenerateColumns=True

Comment: `DataGridView1.DataBindings.Clear()` before you do the query and the continue as you were above, see if it works

Comment: I tried both but still didn't work.

Comment: in Ado.Net, `%` is used with the like instead of the `*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is as I stated in the comment. ADO.Net uses the `%` for the like to maintain consistency with most major Sql engines. But I would like to point out that your query is unsafe and subject to SQL injection so I have included an example of your code using a parameter to pass user input to the command.

Also note that the `OleDbDataAdapter` can be declared in a `Using` statement the same way you did with the `OleDbConnection` Note that you may however have to widen the scope of the dataset (ds) if you plan on doing other things with it.

```
Using conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(connstring)
    Try
        Dim Sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE [Product Name] LIKE @Product"

        Using da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(Sql, conn)
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Product", OleDbType.Varchar).Value = txtSearchProduct.Text & "%"
            Dim ds As New DataSet
            da.Fill(ds)
            DataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
    End Try
End Using
```

Comment: Shouldn't the OleDbType for the parameter be OleDbType.VarChar?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct, I must have been thinking of an ID when I was typing this. Muscle Memory I suppose :D

Comment: Upvote for Using blocks, Parameters and the .Add instead of .AddWithValue.

Answer (score 1):

Like Charles has mentioned its always better to use parameters. My answer is a bit different whereas it uses a reader and not an adapter, and a datatable and not an entire dataset. An adapter should only be used if you intend to write back to the table, or typical scenarios include binding procedures. A DataSet is typically used when you have multiple tables and have a need to relate them. Also note, you most likely want a preceding % in your parameter if you want to match the string regardless of the position in the search column.

```
    Try
        Using conn = New OleDbConnection("YourConnString")
            conn.Open()

            Dim Cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE [Product Name] LIKE @Product", conn)
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product", "'%" & txtSearchProduct.Text & "%'")
            Dim ProductsRDR As OleDbDataReader = Cmd.ExecuteReader

            Dim DTable As New DataTable With {.TableName = "Products"}
            DTable.Load(ProductsRDR)

            DataGridView1.DataSource = DTable


            conn.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
    End Try
```

Comment: I just noticed youre trying to find string in a product name, not an ID, most likely that is not an integer, so I edited my answer to remove the int conversion on the param

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. But your other tips are helpful thanks.

Comment: This is an access table? I think you have to replace % with *

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is replacing the * sign with % in your Sql string, just like this:

This is your wrong Sql string:

```
Dim Sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE [Product Name] LIKE '" & txtSearchProduct.Text & "*'"
```

Change it to this:

```
Dim Sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE [Product Name] LIKE '" & txtSearchProduct.Text & "%'"
```

[image]

Comment: Noted. Thank you very much.

Comment: Wrong, do not concatenate strings to form sql queries. Use parameters.

Comment: No brother, I ensure you it works fine, the & is necessary here.
By the way the last Sql string was for MS SQL Server and it is the same thing as to MS Access .MDB access files such as this code, as I executed it in practical:

Dim selectCommand As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Emp WHERE [EmpName] LIKE '" & txtSearchProduct.Text & "%'", connection)

Comment: This answer replicates the **SQL injection vulnerability** in the original post. I think that was what @Mary was getting at.

Answer (score 0):

This should cover most of the common scenarios out there.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Dim sCommand As SqlCommand
    Dim sAdapter As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim sBuilder As SqlCommandBuilder
    Dim sDs As DataSet
    Dim sTable As DataTable

    Private Sub load_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles load_btn.Click
        Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=pubs;Integrated Security=True"
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Stores"
        Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        connection.Open()
        sCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
        sAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sCommand)
        sBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(sAdapter)
        sDs = New DataSet()
        sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "Stores")
        sTable = sDs.Tables("Stores")
        connection.Close()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = sDs.Tables("Stores")
        DataGridView1.ReadOnly = True
        save_btn.Enabled = False
        DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect

    End Sub

    Private Sub new_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles new_btn.Click
        DataGridView1.[ReadOnly] = False
        save_btn.Enabled = True
        new_btn.Enabled = False
        delete_btn.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub delete_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles delete_btn.Click
        If MessageBox.Show("Do you want to delete this row ?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.Yes Then
            DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Index)
            sAdapter.Update(sTable)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub save_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles save_btn.Click
        sAdapter.Update(sTable)
        DataGridView1.[ReadOnly] = True
        save_btn.Enabled = False
        new_btn.Enabled = True
        delete_btn.Enabled = True
    End Sub
End Class
```